# How to check if two numbers are in range of no more than 10% (JAVA)

Tags: java, numbers, range

Hello people I have something like this 
Two integers for example :

```
int priceSell = 10;
int priceBuy = 5;
```

how can I check if the range is no more than 10 % between those numbers ?

Comment: The range is no more than 10% of what?

Comment: @ user: 10% of 10, or 10% of 5? (Or 10% of 15?) It matters...

Comment: Figure out how you can get the range, then figure out if the other number falls in that range. This is extremely basic math and programming.

Comment: Is it not simple??
10% = 0.1
If the range is > 0.1 , then its more than 10%. Am I wrong?

Comment: @madhairsilence No, it isn't simple, and yes, you could be wrong. 10% *of 1* is 0.1. It doesn't say that in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int priceSell = 10;
int priceBuy = 5;
if (Math.abs(priceSell-priceBuy)>(priceSell/10))
    System.out.println("the price isn't within 10%");
else
    System.out.println("the price is within 10%");
```

-No division by 0

By the way, this answer makes sure the buy price is within 10% of the sell price. The other answer makes sure the sell price is within 10% of the buy price.
And yes, that matters. 90 is within 10% of 100, but 100 isn't within 10% of 90.(10% range of 100 is 90-110. 10% range of 90 is 81-99)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming priceSell is always greater then priceBuy. Change it acording to your needs.

```
if(priceSell!=0){
if(priceBuy/priceSell>=0.9){
 return true;
} else 
return false
}
throw new exception("Dividing by 0");
```

Comment: You can replace `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` with `return condition;`

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume sell price is above the buy price you can do.

```
return priceSell < priceBuy * 1.1;
```

Comment: Because 100% is = to 1